# CGI program can't access external sites through a proxy

Tags: web-development, apache2, proxy

We have a local "server" machine (Web, Samba, LTSP, DHCP.. etc) 192.168.0.11 running Mandriva / Apache2 which connects to internet using another machine as a proxy (Vista 192.168.0.2:6588). Browsers, wget, mcc on 0.11 are able to connect to the net without any problems. However, CGI programs running on this machine are not able to fetch data from external sites. The same programs work correctly when run under Apache on 0.2 machine.

Have tried:

```
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>  
        <Proxy *>  
        Order deny,allow  
        Allow from all  
        </Proxy>  
    ProxyRemote * http://192.168.0.2:6588
    NoProxy 192.168.0.1/254
    </IfModule>
```

in the httpd config file. The proxy module has been enabled.

Is this the correct line of thinking? How to verify that the proxy settings are working? Any other config files need to be checked?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191860/how-to-connect-a-socket-to-an-http-server-through-proxy

Basically, there is no need to change the Apache settings. The CGI programs need to be modified to 'use' the proxy.They need to open the '6588' port on the '192.168.0.2' as given above, send a 'CONNECT servername:80 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' string and then continue to GET/POST as they have been doing.

Simple, once you know how to.

Comment: How to test HTTP proxy using 'telnet' is given here: http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/http-proxy.shtml